# Why isn't the regular expression's "non-capturing" group working?

Tags: python, regex

In the snippet below, the **non-capturing group `"(?:aaa)"`** should be ignored in the matching result,

The result should be `"_bbb"` only.

However, I get `"aaa_bbb"` in the matching result; only when I specify group(2) does it show `"_bbb"`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "aaa_bbb"
>>> print(re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", s).group())

aaa_bbb
```

Comment: cool, thanks for editting, and answers pointing out the concept of non-capturing group

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`group()` and `group(0)` will return the entire match. Subsequent groups are actual capture groups.

```
>>> print (re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", string1).group(0))
aaa_bbb
>>> print (re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", string1).group(1))
_bbb
>>> print (re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", string1).group(2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
IndexError: no such group
```

If you want the same behavior than `group()`:

`" ".join(re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", string1).groups())`

Answer (score 148):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of a "non-capturing group". The text matched by a non-capturing group still becomes part of the overall regex match.

Both the regex `(?:aaa)(_bbb)` and the regex `(aaa)(_bbb)` return `aaa_bbb` as the overall match.  The difference is that the first regex has one capturing group which returns `_bbb` as its match, while the second regex has two capturing groups that return `aaa` and `_bbb` as their respective matches.  In your Python code, to get `_bbb`, you'd need to use `group(1)` with the first regex, and `group(2)` with the second regex.

The main benefit of non-capturing groups is that you can add them to a regex without upsetting the numbering of the capturing groups in the regex.  They also offer (slightly) better performance as the regex engine doesn't have to keep track of the text matched by non-capturing groups.

If you really want to exclude `aaa` from the overall regex match then you need to use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  In this case, positive lookbehind does the trick: `(?<=aaa)_bbb`.  With this regex, `group()` returns `_bbb` in Python.  No capturing groups needed.

My recommendation is that if you have the ability to use capturing groups to get part of the regex match, use that method instead of lookaround.

Comment: This is a much more useful answer than that accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
print(re.match(r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", string1).group(1))
```

`group()` is same as `group(0)` and Group `0` is always present and it's the **whole RE** match.

Answer (score 3):

[TFM](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects):

`class re.MatchObject`

`group([group1, ...])`

Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. **Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string.**

Answer (score 1):

To go along with Jan Goyvaert's answer:

> The main benefit of non-capturing groups is that you can add them to a regex without upsetting the numbering of the capturing groups in the regex.

Why add a group that doesn't upset the numbering of the groups?

- [to organize your expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512530/246801)... make it easier to read
- allow for there being defining characteristics that [you ultimately don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3512530/246801)
- [to give precedence to other operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195624/246801)

OP's example, `r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)"`, draws my eye (and brain) to "aaa" but there's nothing special about it... to me, it merely seems adjacent to what really matters, "_bbb".

I think it should actually be one of either:

- `r"aaa(_bbb)"`: if "aaa" isn't important to how you/we read the regex, "aaa" has no meaning to us
- `r"(?:aaa(_bbb))"`: if "aaa_bbb" is a single thing we should (mentally) consider as a whole, but in the end we only use "_bbb"

All three are equivalent from the perspective of the regex engine:

```py
s = "aaa_bbb"
for pattern in [r"(?:aaa)(_bbb)", r"aaa(_bbb)", r"(?:aaa(_bbb))"]:
    m = re.match(pattern, s)

    print(pattern)
    print("=" * len(pattern))
    print(f"groups(): {m.groups()}")
    for i in range(1, len(m.groups()) + 1):
        print(f"  group({i}): {m.group(i)}")
    print()
```

```
(?:aaa)(_bbb)
=============
groups(): ('_bbb',)
  group(1): _bbb

aaa(_bbb)
=========
groups(): ('_bbb',)
  group(1): _bbb

(?:aaa(_bbb))
=============
groups(): ('_bbb',)
  group(1): _bbb
```

For a real world example, I want to parse the output from a Unix-like time command:

```
% /usr/bin/time -l foo
...
        9.87 real         6.54 user         3.21 sys
...
```

My original Python regex was:

```py
import re

line = "        9.87 real         6.54 user         3.21 sys"

pattern = r"\s+(\d+\.\d+) real\s+(\d+\.\d+) user\s+(\d+\.\d+) sys"
```

which gives me the correct groupings:

```py
m = re.match(pattern, line)

print(m.groups())  # ('9.87', '6.54', '3.21')
print(m.group(1))  # 9.87
print(m.group(2))  # 6.54
print(m.group(3))  # 3.21
```

But the labels at the end of the value kept throwing my eyes off, and I kept seeing "real\s+(\d+.\d+)" instead of "(\d+.\d+) real".

I could try to add parens to visually distinguish the "meta groups", which is a little better, visually, for me:

```py
pattern = r"\s+((\d+\.\d+) real)\s+((\d+\.\d+) user)\s+((\d+\.\d+) sys)"
```

but that breaks the logic of the groupings I want:

```py
m = re.match(pattern, line)

print(m.groups())  # ('9.87 real', '9.87', '6.54 user', '6.54', '3.21 sys', '3.21')
print(m.group(1))  # 9.87 real
print(m.group(2))  # 9.87
print(m.group(3))  # 6.54 user
print(m.group(4))  # 6.54
print(m.group(5))  # 3.21 sys
print(m.group(6))  # 3.21
```

Making those meta groups *non grouping* gives me a better visual (my eyes still do some back-and-forth, but at least there are clear boundaries) for my meta groups:

```py
pattern = r"\s+(?:(\d+\.\d+) real)\s+(?:(\d+\.\d+) user)\s+(?:(\d+\.\d+) sys)"
```

and it leaves logic of the grouping alone:

```py
m = re.match(pattern, line)

print(m.groups())  # ('9.87', '6.54', '3.21')
print(m.group(1))  # 9.87
print(m.group(2))  # 6.54
print(m.group(3))  # 3.21
```

Comment: I didn't read your whole answer but I like the first three points in which you contextualize why non-capture group is useful

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `group(1)` to get just the part captured by the parenthesis (`_bbb` in this case).

`group()` without parameters will return the whole string the complete regular expression matched, no matter if some parts of it were additionally captured by parenthesis or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the groups method on the match object instead of group.  It returns a list of all capture buffers.  The group method with no argument is returning the entire match of the regular expression.