# How to use regex non-capturing groups format in Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In the following code I want to get just the digits between '-' and 'u'.
I thought i could apply regular expression non capturing groups format (?: … )
to ignore everything from '-' to the first digit. But output always include it. How can i use noncapturing groups format to generate correct ouput?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a' : [1,2,3,4], 
     'b' : ['41u -428u', '31u - 68u', '11u - 58u', '21u - 318u']
    })

df['b'].str.extract('((?:-[ ]*)[0-9]*)', expand=True)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is explained very well in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703029/why-regular-expressions-non-capturing-group-is-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't included in the inner group, but it's still included as part of the outer group. A non-capturing group does't necessarily imply it isn't captured at all... just that that group does not explicitly get saved in the output. It is still captured as part of any enclosing groups.

Just do not put them into the `()` that define the capturing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a' : [1,2,3,4], 
     'b' : ['41u -428u', '31u - 68u', '11u - 58u', '21u - 318u']
    })

df['b'].str.extract(r'- ?(\d+)u', expand=True)

     0
0  428
1   68
2   58
3  318
```

That way you match anything that has a `'-'` in front (mabye followed by a aspace), a `'u'` behind and numbers between the both.

Where,

```
-      # literal hyphen
\s?    # optional space—or you could go with \s* if you expect more than one
(\d+)  # capture one or more digits 
u      # literal "u"
```

Comment: This returns a `<input>:1: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \d`. with compiler warnings turned on. I suggest you use raw strings.

Comment: @coldspeed very good suggestion - I just tested in pyfiddle and they do not show warnings. thx

Comment: Hmm, our patterns are ditto. I'll delete my answer ;-)

Comment: @coldspeed not quite - I used a space, forgetting about \s all the time

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying too complicated a regex. What about:

```
df['b'].str.extract(r'-(.*)u', expand=True)

      0
0   428
1    68
2    58
3   318
```

Comment: This also returns a DeprecationWarning with compiler warnings enabled, because your string isn't a raw-string.

Comment: Fair enough, am I right in saying that `r'-(.*)u'` would solve that? I'm not all that familiar with it TBH

Comment: Indeed, it would. ;-)