# How to identify a series of numbers inside a paragraph

Tags: python, regex

I have a paragraph/sentence from which I want to identify

1. any series of number 6 digits or more
2. any series of numbers with a "-"  (dash)

but I don't want to identify

1. any numbers preceded by a $(dollar)
2. any series of numbers with , (comma)

How can I achieve this?

The regex I tried is: `r'(?:\s|^)(\d-?(\s)?){6,}(?=[?\s]|$)'`
but its not accurate.

I'm looking for these patterns inside a paragraph

- 123-456-789
- 123-456
- 123 456
- 123 456 789
  It may also contain full stop(.) at the end too
  but it should ignore the following patterns
- $123654
- $ 123654
- 12,4569
- 123*123*7732
- 123h434k5454

Comment: Do you mean like this perhaps using a capturing group? `(?<!\S)(?:\$(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:-\d+)+|6+))(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/VEVU8L/1

Comment: Maybe `(?<![\d$])(?<!\d,)(?:\d+(?:-\d+)+|\d{6,})(?![\d,])` will do?

Comment: With 6 digits instead of the number 6 `(?<!\S)(?:\$(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:-\d+)+|\d{6,}))(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/YW6Md5/1

Comment: Please see [ask] a question with a [mcve] and include sample data and expected output. That would help identify which regex is best to use. I suspect you are using `Python`?

Comment: Yes its almost accurate, but I want to ignore any number preceding with dollar+space too eg. $123654,  $ 123654

Comment: You could match 0 or more whitespace chars after matching the dollar sign `(?<!\S)(?:\$\s*(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:-\d+)+|\d{6,}))(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/R5C0bl/1 It matches all values, but the values you are looking for to keep are in group 1 (Highlighted in green on regex101)

Comment: I've updated the question with samples. @Thefourthbird

Comment: Its for a image to text conversion program. so I want to ignore secure information like SSNs, a/c numbers... so the image can be handwritten documents. so Just added that criteria forecasting the issue when adding a space between numbers in the handwritten doc..it can be avoided too

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird 123 456 123 456 789 can be avoided. If it is required in future, how can I add that condition?

Comment: You could change the quantifier from `{6,}` to `{3,}` https://regex101.com/r/pIHm5Q/1

Comment: (?<!\S)(?:\$\s*(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:[ -]\d+)+|\d{3,}))(?!\S) looks coo except that its not ignoring amounts.. $ and $<space> patterns..I don't want them at all..

Comment: python @Thefourthbird

Comment: @PraphulNangeelil See an example in Python https://ideone.com/FzFLrF

Comment: I've updated with one more condition that I missed. ie to incorporate a full stop at the end,

Comment: If it is for both the hyphenated digits and the digits with spaces, you can make the dot optional `(?<!\S)(?:\$\s*(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:[ -]\d+)+\.?|\d{3,}))(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/i4uxZz/1

Comment: ya..got it..but how to get the green color group of the result set only...cos $ and $<space> are in blue.. i dont want to consider them...

Comment: its not loading @Thefourthbird ... broken page

Comment: @PraphulNangeelil I have added an answer with 2 demo links. I will cleanup the comments a bit as it is a long list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep.

Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) the group 1 values will be returned.

Afterwards you might filter out the empty strings.

```
(?<!\S)(?:\$\s*\d+(?:\,\d+)?|(\d+(?:[ -]\d+)+\.?|\d{3,}))(?!\S)
```

In parts

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the left
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\$\s*` Match a dollar sign, 0+ whitespace chars
  - `\d+(?:\,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional comma digits part
  - `|` Or
  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
    - `(?:[ -]\d+)+\.?` Repeat a space or `-` 1+ times followed by an optional `.`
    - `|` Or
    - `\d{3,}` Match 3 or more digits (Or use `{6,}` for 6 or more
  - `)` Close group 1
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eu4xA9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/V43Xy5) | [Another Python demo](https://rextester.com/AACX4150)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\S)(?:\$\s*(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:[ -]\d+)+\.?|\d{3,}))(?!\S)"

test_str = ("123456\n"
    "1234567890\n"
    "12345\n\n"
    "12,123\n"
    "etc...)

print(list(filter(None, re.findall(regex, test_str))))
```

Output

```
['123456', '1234567890', '12345', '1-2-3', '123-456-789', '123-456-789.', '123-456', '123 456', '123 456 789', '123 456 789.', '123 456 123 456 789', '123', '456', '123', '456', '789']
```

Comment: my current requirement is to use the result  in `if(re.match(regex, field.value.text.lower())):` this returns all matches and groups..  I can not use the re.findall() here..I want only the group1 result in the re.match()

Comment: [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) from which you can get the [group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group)

Comment: You mean, `re.match(regex, field.value.text.lower()).group` like this?

Comment: Like `.group(1)` See this page for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703029/why-isnt-the-regular-expressions-non-capturing-group-working

Comment: gotcha! in our case, our matching results are in group(1), right?

Comment: That is correct. Note that re.match matches `If zero or more characters at the beginning of string` Else you could look at [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)

Comment: How can I add the condition to add these type of patterns `+123456565  +  12345675`

Comment: @PraphulNangeelil Hi there, sorry for the late reponse. You can do it like this https://regex101.com/r/yDzRU3/1 You can prepend a optional group with a `+` and an optional space before it `(?:\+ ?)?\d{3,}`

Comment: if I want to add any other characters in the future, suppose I want to add @  --------  `(?:\+ ?)?(?:\@ ?)?\d{3,}`  is this correct?  `(?<!\S)(?:\$\s*(?:\d+(?:\,\d+)?)|(\d+(?:[ -]\d+)+\.?|(?:\+ ?)?(?:\@ ?)?\d{6,}))(?!\S)`

Comment: This part `(?:@ ?)?` will accept an `@` followed by an optional space. If you want to allow more characters, you could use a character class allowing any of the listed llike `(?:[@+] ?)?`

Comment: but it fails when the patter is  +123-456-565

Comment: If you want it for both the alternations, you could prepend it before the alternation https://regex101.com/r/73VCnN/1 else you have to add it per alternative what you would allow. https://regex101.com/r/tpKoXT/1 Note that you are extending the original question, and accounting for all the side effects will make the pattern larger.

Comment: Yes,, the basic requirement has been satisfied by you. but these are the issues that I'm anticipating. that's why I clarified all my queries. Thanks a lot. You helped a lot.