# How to extract ABC and XZ from ABC XYZ?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract `ABC` and `XZ` from the following string:

- `ABC XYZ`

I tried this:

- `(ABC) (X(?:Y)Z)`

But it extracts `ABC` and `XYZ`.

Comment: No that does not answer my question and I do not appreciate closing my question like that.

Comment: You do have a capturing group *around* the non-capturing group, so of course it shows up in the result…‽

Comment: I need to extract `ABC` and `XZ`  from `ABC XYZ`.  So yes I need to exclude the `Y` from the second group, hence the nested non-capturing group.

Comment: `(ABC) (X(?:Y)Z)`

Comment: Why doesn't it work? I won't know because my question is closed and pointed to a useless answer.

Comment: A non-capturing group won’t exclude anything from a surrounding capturing group. That’s not what it does. It’s just a group which you can use for its grouping behavior, *without having it show up as an additional capture.*

Comment: Then how do I extract `XZ` from `XYZ`?

Comment: Rephrase your question towards that and away from the red herring of non-capturing groups, and this could be reopened.

Comment: You can't have non consecutive characters in a single group. It's the normal behaviour of regex. It's not possible to extract `XZ` from `XYZ`, there're absolutly no way to do such job.

Comment: The [Why isn't the regular expression's “non-capturing” group working?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703139/3832970) explains that *"the text matched by a non-capturing group still becomes part of the overall regex match"* and **is a valid answer to this question, too**. @deceze Please consider reclosing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful to you at all, but I noticed you added a javascript tag.

If you want, you could try the following regex: https://regex101.com/r/JB3iNj/1

With the following code:

```
    var myString = "ABC XYZ";
    var myRegexp = /(ABC) (X)Y(Z)/g;
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    var s1 = match[1]
    var s2 = (match[2] + match[3])
    console.log(s1 + " " + s2)
```

Comment: I know it's not a great answer, but didn't want you to feel like all was lost. If you tell us more about your use case, might be able to help to a better degree.

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed that this is, in fact, impossible.